# In the definition of Strong Feferman Set Theory, what does this phrase mean?

Tags: set-theory

In [this](http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/feferman_set_theory.html) post, Mike Shulman talks about Strong Feferman Set Theory, arguing that it deals with the foundational issues raised by category theory in an especially straightforward manner.

Mike explains:

> To ZFC (or your favorite set theory) we add a constant symbol $U$
>   together with the axiom “$U$ is a universe,” and also an axiom schema
>   stating that for any statement $\varphi$, all of whose parameters are
>   in $U$ but which does not mention $U$ explicitly, we have $\varphi^U \Leftrightarrow \varphi$.

What does the expression 'all of whose parameters are in $U$ but which does not mention $U$ explicitly' actually mean?

Comment: To help calibrate the level of the answer, would you mind saying whether you are comfortable with the general concept of a "parameter
" in a formula?

Comment: @CarlMummert, I am familiar with 'free variables', but I do not know if that is the meaning of 'parameter'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of "parameters". Suppose we are trying to write an axiom that for all sets $x,y$ there is a $z = \{x,y\}$. We would write the axiom as:
$$
(\forall x)(\forall y)(\exists z)(\forall w)[w \in z \leftrightarrow w = x \lor w = y]
$$
Here $x$ and $y$ are called (informally) the "parameters" of this axiom, because they are the sets upon which the constructed set $z$ will depend.

The axiom scheme in the question is trying to say that the elements of $U$ have the same properties from the perspective of $U$ that the do from the perspective of the entire universe. For example, a set $x$ is "countable in $U$" if and only if it is countable:
$$
(\forall x \in U) \left [ (\exists f \in U)(\text{$f$ is a bijection from $x$ to $\omega$}) \leftrightarrow (\exists g)(\text{$g$ is a bijection from $x$ to $\omega$})\right ]
$$
This can be put into the form $(\forall x \in U)[\phi^U(x) \leftrightarrow \phi(x)]$, so $x$ is a "parameter" of that formula $\phi$ in this scheme.

Comment: The countability is a very good example!

Comment: @AsafKaragila and CarlMummert... Thanks for your answers. But, I'm still not getting it. Are we just saying that if $\phi$ is a formula not mentioning $U$, then the 'universal-relativized to $U$' closure of $\phi^U \Leftrightarrow \phi$ holds?

Comment: @user18921: yes.

Comment: @CarlMummert, okay well that makes sense. I also think I get what you're saying about parameters. Basically, if we have a sentence, then the outermost universally quantified variables are called its parameters. Is this correct, or have I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: @user18921: it's an informal usage of the term. The underlying idea is that when we have a particular model, we want to replace all the free variables of $\phi$ with actual elements of the model to obtain a particular instance of the scheme $\phi^U \leftrightarrow \phi$. I would call those elements of the model the "parameters". But, to achieve this goal syntactically with axioms, we instead universally quantify over the free variables of $\phi$ (or universally quantify over $U$, in this case). This is all an analogy to the formal definition of "definability with parameters" in model theory.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the symbol $U$ does not appear in $\varphi$, and the schema is something like that:

$$\forall p_1\in U\ldots\forall p_n\in U(\varphi^U(p_1,\ldots,p_n)\leftrightarrow\varphi(p_1,\ldots,p_n))$$

Where $\varphi^U$ is the relativized formula (which is a recursive syntactical modification of the formula $\varphi$ which happens at the meta-theory).

Comment: The doesn't really explain, "all of whose parameters are in U but which does not mention U." Can you give examples of $\phi$ which satisfy this condition, and ones that fail it?

Comment: @Thomas: Syntactically $\varphi$, which is a string of letters, can have the letter $U$ (which is a constant symbol in the language) occurring. In that case it explicitly mentions $U$, but otherwise it doesn't. $\forall x(x\notin y)$ is a formula with a free variable $y$ which doesn't mention $U$. On the other hand $\forall x(x\notin y)\rightarrow y\in U$ does mention $U$. The parameters are the assignments to the free variables. So we just require that they come from $U$ and not from anywhere else in the universe.

Comment: Ah, so that "all of whose parameters are in $U$" is not really a statement about $\varphi$, but about where we will be interpreting $\varphi$. The language strongly implies it is a statement about $\varphi$, and not about the recursive axiom scheme.

Comment: @Thomas: Hence Carl's comment to the OP.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: the way to understand the wording of the quoted statement is: the scheme is intended to mean that, in any model, if we expand the language to include a constant symbol for each element of the model, and then write down a *sentence* $\phi$ in the expanded language that *literally* includes only constant symbols corresponding to elements of $U$, then the sentence $\phi^U \leftrightarrow \phi$ holds. The way the axiom scheme actually achieves this, independent of any model, is by using universal quantifiers over $U$ for all the free variables of $\phi$ in the scheme.

Answer (score 1):

A parameter is basically some value that is a part of the formula. For example, take the statement "every subset of $\mathbb R$ with an upper bound has a least upper bound in $\mathbb R$". Roughly speaking, this can be realized as a formula "every subset of $x$ with an upper bound has a least upper bound $x$" with parameter $x := \mathbb R$.

Now, in this example, we do not need to use a parameter if we do not want to, since we can just include the definition of $\mathbb R$ in the statement itself. This is not always the case, however. For example, if a parameter is not definable in the language you are using, it obviously can not just be replaced with its definition.

So, what the axiom is saying is that the formula $\phi$ does not just need to be a sequence of set theoretic symbols, but can include any set as well.

This also has an important consequence for what you can and can not proof. For any formula $\phi$, we have a single axiom asserting that $\phi^U \iff \phi$ for all possible parameters, instead of an axiom of each combination of parameters. Since proofs can only invoke a finite number of axioms, this makes a difference.